# I thought C# has lexical scoping, but why this example shows dynamic scoping behavior?

Tags: c#, scope, closures

```
    var x = 1;
    Func<int,int> f = y => x + y;
    x = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(f(1));
```

The output is 3. I would assume it is 2, according to https://web.archive.org/web/20170426121932/http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~clarkson/courses/csci4223/2013sp/lec/lec12.pdf

Comment: You changed the value of `x` before invoking `f`.  Why would you not expect to use the current value of `x`?

Comment: Why 4? maybe you thought 2?

Comment: And why 4? I see how you could think f(1)=2 but where would you get 4?

Comment: @KirkWoll read the link, it uses the value of x at the time the function is defined, not at the time it is invoked.

Comment: Read the [MSDN page on Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) especially the "Remarks" section which describes this behaviour as a "captured" variable.

Comment: @BlackICE You have that reversed.  It uses the value of variable at the time it is invoked, not the time it is defined.  Closures close over *variables*, not *values*.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the document says: _Rule of Lexical Scope: the body of a function is evaluated in the old dynamic environment that existed at the time the function was defined, not the current environment when the function is called._

Comment: @BlackICE And was that document specifically discussing closure's in C#?  It is describing something entirely different.  [Ben's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16220834/1159478) explains how C# can still use lexical scoping despite the fact that closures still close over variables, but it doesn't change the fact that they do indeed close over variables, not values.

Comment: @BlackICE: And that's exactly what happens.  See my answer for clarification.  The environment (collection of *variables*, but not values thereof) that existed at the time the lambda was defined *IS* used -- which is to say the environment within `DefineIt()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a subtlety concerning lexical scoping that PDF doesn't fully explain.  Its example actually has two different variables named `x`, it does not reassign the value of the first `x` (and indeed functional languages may not allow mutation).

C# is lexically scoped -- it looks up `x` at the point of definition of the lambda, not when the delegate is invoked.  But: `x` resolves to a variable, not a value, and it reads the variable's value at the time of invocation.

Here is a more complete example:

```
int InvokeIt( Func<int, int> f )
{
   int x = 2;
   return f(1);
}

Func<int, int> DefineIt()
{
   int x = 1;
   Func<int, int> d = (y => x + y);
   x = 3;  // <-- the PDF never does this
   return d;
}

Console.WriteLine(InvokeIt(DefineIt()));
```

The lambda binds to the `x` *variable* that exists *inside* `DefineIt`.  The value (`x = 1`) at the point of definition is irrelevant.  The *variable* is later set to `x = 3`.

But it is clearly not *dynamic scope* either, because the `x = 2` inside `InvokeIt` is not used.

Comment: sorry, this is hurting my brain, I'm trying to run your example to understand what's going on but I'm getting compiler error that DefineIt() does not return a value. nevermind, you updated it.

Comment: @BlackICE: Sorry about that, now fixed.

Comment: ok, I think I get how this is working with the different scopes of x and the lambda pointing to the variable, thanks Ben.

Comment: Is it possible that there exists an imperative language that is lexical scoped, but its closure captures values only, and thus return 2 in SO's example?

Comment: @colinfang: Sure, for example C++ with the `[=]` lambda specifier.  Well, I guess that's not values *only*, and it isn't truly capturing a value, but the variable captured is a *copy* of the original.

Comment: Isn't the reason this is the case is that all variables in C# are references, as if the .NET framework was managing the pointers for us behind the scenes?

Comment: @NH.: That doesn't make a very good explanation because it's not true.  Variables of "value type" are not references.  They can be stored inside a reference type, though, which is what happens behind the scenes when a lambda or anonymous delegate captures them.

Answer (score 24):

This question was [the subject of my blog on the 20th of May 2013](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/20/what-is-lexical-scoping/). Thanks for the great question!

---

You're misunderstanding what "lexically scoped" means. Let's quote from the document you linked to:

> the body of a function is evaluated in the old dynamic environment that existed at the time the function was defined, not the current environment when the function is called.

Here's your code:

```
int  x = 1;
Func<int,int> f = y => x + y;
x = 2;
Console.WriteLine(f(1));
```

Now, what is "the dynamic environment that exists at the time the function was defined"?  Think about an "environment" as a class. That class contains a mutable field for every variable. So this is the same as:

```
Environment e = new Environment();
e.x = 1;
Func<int,int> f = y => e.x + y;
e.x = 2;
Console.WriteLine(f(1));
```

When `f` is evaluated, `x` is looked up *in the environment e that existed when f was created*.  The *contents* of that environment have changed, but *the environment that `f` is bound to* is the same environment. (Note that *this is actually the code that the C# compiler generates*! When you use a local variable in a lambda, the compiler generates a special "environment" class and turns every usage of the local into a usage of a field.)

Let me give you an example of what the world would look like if C# was dynamically scoped. Consider the following:

```
class P
{
    static void M()
    {
        int x = 1;
        Func<int, int> f = y => x + y;
        x = 2;
        N(f);
    }
    static void N(Func<int, int> g)
    {
        int x = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(g(100));
    }
}
```

If C# was dynamically scoped then this would print "103" because evaluating `g` evaluates `f`, and in a dynamically scoped language, evaluating `f` would look up the value of `x` *in the current environment*. In the *current* environment, `x` is 3. In the environment that existed when `f` was created, `x` is 2. Again, the value of `x` in that environment has changed; as your document points out, the environment is a *dynamic environment*. But *which environment is relevant* doesn't change.

Most languages these days are not dynamically scoped, but there are a few. PostScript, for example -- the language that runs on printers -- is dynamically scoped.

Comment: So you are saying that C# closure captures variables as its environment instead of the values of variables. Is it possible that there exists an imperative language that is lexical scoped, but its closure captures values only, and thus return 2 in SO's example?

Comment: @colinfang yes. In the new c++ there is a syntax for closing over both variables and values.

Comment: Hmm, value type is named after that the variable is copied by value. I don't get why for a closure the value type isn't designed to simply "captured by value", just like in a method. Likewise for reference type captured by a closure use "copy by reference".

Comment: @colinfang: Think about it this way. If you said `int x = 1 ; f(x); x = 2; f(x);` you would expect that the result is the same as `f(1); f(2);`, right?  If you said `int x = 1; Action a = ()=>{f(x);}; a(); x = 2; a();` then why would you expect that to be different?  Shouldn't you be able to *extract repeated code into a lambda* without changing the meaning of the code?  It would be strange for that new code to have the meaning `f(1); f(1);`, right?